# Dynamic ID (Kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, widget, kivy-language

Sorry for the English mistakes, but I'm using Google translator to try to communicate, because I didn't find any solution in the forum where I live.

I've searched everywhere and I understand that there's no way to put an id on a dynamically added widget. But then how do I get some information, for example, from a dynamically added textinput?

Please help me, because I'm already getting desperate with the same problem for a week.

Python code:

```
import sys, os, pyautogui
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MeuLayout(ScrollView):
    def criar_pessoa(self, numero):
        if numero.isnumeric():
            if int(numero) > 20:
                pyautogui.alert('Excedeu o valor limite!')
            else:
                i=1
                while i < int(numero)+1:
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text= f'Nome da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y= None, height= 100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=f'Sobrenome da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(write_tab= False, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(write_tab= False,multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=f'Email da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=f'Telefone da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(write_tab= False,multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(write_tab= False,multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='___________________________________________________________', size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='___________________________________________________________', size_hint_y=None, height=100))

                    i+=1

        else:
            pyautogui.alert('Coloque apenas números!')
        self.ids.numero_pessoas.text = ''

class AppCadastro(App):
    def build(self):
        return MeuLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    AppCadastro().run()
```

Kv code:

```
<MeuLayout>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        id: grid
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        Label:
            text: 'Seu email:'
            font_size: 17
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            TextInput:
                id: email
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 300
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

        Label:
            text: 'Sua senha:'
            font_size: 18
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            TextInput:
                id: senha
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                password: True
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 300
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30



        Label:
            text : 'Quantidade de pessoas: (limite: 20)'
            font_size: 18
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            TextInput:
                id: numero_pessoas
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                size_hint: .1, .1
                size_hint: None, None
                height: 30
                width: 30
                on_text_validate: root.criar_pessoa(numero_pessoas.text)

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 way to access widgets dynamically which are created in python side:

**First way:**

```
a = TextInput(write_tab= False, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
self.ids.grid.add_widget(a)
```

For get these widgets text:

```
print(a.text) #in same function
```

If you need to access these widgets from another class, you need to use `App.get_running_app()`.

**Second way:**

Accessing parent widget and return its children:

```
print(self.ids.grid.children)
```

It returns list of children and you can pick'em by one by. But in here , you need to search'em for find which one you want to access. For that, you can use `isinstance` or checking their text or other properties.

Comment: But how do I get the text typed by the user in TextInputado?

Comment: I edited my code check it for clear example. After you accessing these widgets, just need to get their text like : `widget.text`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking so long to help a stranger ❤️
Tomorrow I will go to work and test the code, as I have no way of testing it at home.
But in advance, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Thank you again. That allows me. Now you're going to face other problems here lol

Comment: One last note, in case you can help me and I'm not getting in the way: How do I access this variable in another method? I've already used App.get_running_app(), as you taught me, but it won't. I must be using it the wrong way.

Comment: to be more specific, I'll put the code and the error:
n= App.get_running_app().root.create_person.name[0].text
        print(n)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I think you're trying to get name attribute from function. You need to share minimal code and what you need to do so someone help you.

Comment: So I think it would be better to open another subject, because the one in this conversation has already been resolved. Thank you very much